# Verilog: Converted Integer Not Working for For loop

Tags: for-loop, binary, verilog

I am writing a program in Verilog that accepts a binary value, converts it to Integer, and then prints "Hello, World!" that amount of times.

However, whenever I run the program, there is no display of Hello, World. Here is the code:

```
// Internal Variable
wire [0:4] two_times_rotate;

// Multiply the rotate_imm by two (left shift)
assign {two_times_rotate} = rotate_imm << 1;
integer i, times_rotated;

// Convert two_times_rotate into an integer
always @( two_times_rotate )
begin
  times_rotated = two_times_rotate;
end

initial 
begin

for (i = 0; i < times_rotated; i = i + 1)
begin
  $display("Hello, World");
end

end

assign {out} = in;
 endmodule
```

I tried using the following for loop instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i = i + 1)
```

And this one prints Hello, World seven times, like it should.

****UPDATE****

This is what I have in my code so far. I am trying to do a for that compares bits instead. It is still not working. How do I fully convert from binary to integer in a way that I can use it in the comparison in the for loop?

```
 module immShifter(input[0:31] in, input[0:3] rotate_imm, 
              output[0:31] out);

 // Internal Variable
 wire [0:4] two_times_rotate;
 reg [0:4] i;

 // Multiply the rotate_imm by two (left shift)
 assign {two_times_rotate} = rotate_imm << 1;
 integer times_rotated, for_var;

 // Convert two_times_rotate into an integer
 always @( two_times_rotate )
 begin
    assign{times_rotated} = two_times_rotate;
 end

 initial 
 begin

 assign{i} = 5'b00000;
 assign{for_var} = times_rotated;
 for (i = 5'b00000; i < times_rotated; i = i + 5'b00001)
 begin
   $display("Hello, World");
 end

 end

 assign {out} = in;
endmodule
```

Comment: Looks like the first few lines of your code are missing

Comment: @jean28, I recommend not put `assign` inside `always` blocks or `initial` blocks. Most designers declare packed arrays are in (little endian)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness] format (i.e. `[31:0]`).

Answer (score 1):

`times_rotated` is `32'bX` at time 0 when the for-loop is being evaluated. The for-loop is checking `i < 32'bX`, which is false.

---

Based on your update, this may be what you are intending:

```
module immShifter( input [31:0] in, input [3:0] rotate_imm, output [31:0] out );
  integer i, times_rotated;
  always @*
  begin
    times_rotated = rotate_imm << 1;
    for (i = 0; i < times_rotated; i++)
      $display("Hello, World");
    $display(""); // empty line as separate between changes to rotate_imm
  end
  assign out = in;
endmodule
```

Comment: So how do I turn it into an integer so that it checks the correct condition?

Comment: @jean28, what do you intend the correct condition to be? At this point everything is running at time 0. Everything runs in parallel in Verilog, so the order of execution is on the whims of the simulator's scheduler.